# Spacing In VLayout

Tags: smartgwt

I am working inside a Tabpane and I want to have 2 buttons on the bottom-right of the tap-pane, so I thought I just add a LayoutSpacer, but this resulted in

[image]

but I wanted it to look like

[image]

How can I make my Layoutspacer "bigger"?

Comment: Can you explain the difference in words?

Comment: Currently if I use a layoutspacer the buttons that follow are in the middle of the screen, because the layoutspacer is not "big" enough. What I want is that the spacer uses enough space that my buttons are at the bottom of my screen. If there is another way I would do that, like adding buttons to the bottom of the layout ( like a reverses VLayout ).

Comment: try with [layoutspacer.setHeight100()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHeight100%28%29) or try [layoutspacer.setHeight("100%")](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHeight%28java.lang.String%29) or `layoutspacer.setHeight("*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Smart GWT there are different methods to set the size of the component's vertical dimension.

Try with any one

1. [canvas.setHeight100()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHeight100%28%29)
2. [canvas.setHeight("100%")](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHeight%28java.lang.String%29)
3. `canvas.setHeight("*")`

   [Layout](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/layout/Layout.html)s may specially interpret percentage sizes on their children, and also allow "*" as a size.